# Changing Userform Label derived from one worksheet when inputting on a different worksheet

Tags: excel, dynamic, userform, label, vba

I have a worksheet that runs a weightlifting meet. Last year I had created a tab that would give information on the current lifter and on who was lifting next.

[left side - Display, right side - input tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfxc5.jpg)

When I input an "x" in columns R, S, T, or W on the data tab, it changes the information in the BenchGenerator tab, like so:

[Updated Display tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayvqi.jpg)

What I want to do is make a userform display to run on a different screen so people can see this information.  I had accomplished this last year by widening excel and using two view windows - display on the second screen and running the meet on the computer.  It was ok but very clunky looking.  With a floating userform tab, it would look fantastic. I am new to this, but got the form floating:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
UserForm1.Show (vbModeless)
End Sub
```

And got the labels to initially populate:

[Userform Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaMcj.jpg)

Using this code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
UserForm1.Label1.Caption = Sheets("BenchGenerator").Range("c4").Value
UserForm1.Label2.Caption = Sheets("BenchGenerator").Range("c5").Value
UserForm1.Label3.Caption = Sheets("BenchGenerator").Range("c6").Value
UserForm1.Label4.Caption = Sheets("BenchGenerator").Range("d3").Value
UserForm1.Label5.Caption = Sheets("BenchGenerator").Range("d4").Value
UserForm1.Label6.Caption = Sheets("BenchGenerator").Range("d5").Value
UserForm1.Label7.Caption = Sheets("BenchGenerator").Range("d6").Value
End Sub
```

What it doesn't currently do is update the captions when I input the "x" in the data tab.

As I mentioned, this is my first foray into userforms and looking through mountains of code trying to figure this out, it will not be my last as there is lots to accomplish with them.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close to getting this to work.  The problem is that your calling a new form every time a change occurs.

Declare your form as an object outside of the `Sub` that creates (`Show`) it.

You can then access it to update labels from another `Sub` that has the same scope.

Create an `UpdateForm` sub for example and call it from your `Worksheet_Change` event.

Try this, place the following code in a new Module:

```
Dim myForm As Object

Sub launchForm()
    Set myForm = UserForm1
    myForm.Show (vbModeless)
End Sub

Sub updateForm()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = Sheets("BenchGenerator")

    'Update label values here
    myForm.Label1.Caption = wks.Range("C4").Value
    myForm.Label2.Caption = wks.Range("C5").Value
    myForm.Label3.Caption = wks.Range("C6").Value
    myForm.Label4.Caption = wks.Range("D3").Value
    myForm.Label5.Caption = wks.Range("D4").Value
    myForm.Label6.Caption = wks.Range("D5").Value
    myForm.Label7.Caption = wks.Range("D6").Value
End Sub
```

---

If you use `Worksheet_Change` to update the form you'll want to verify the form exist or just skip any errors in the event if it doesn't.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    updateForm
End Sub
```

Comment: I saved a test file and uploaded it [here](https://ufile.io/qarxj) so that you can see it working.  It's available for 30 days.

Comment: I am so close - so created a module, and added that code to it, clicking Run: Run Sub/UserForm: launchForm, the form pops up.  Then when I "x" a value on the Data sheet, and hit Run: Run  Sub/UserForm: updateForm, the Labels change PERFECTLY!  I have created a shape on my Data sheet and assigned the launchForm macro to it - what do I need to do to trigger the update form event when I enter an "x" into one of the columns on that sheet? :)

Comment: ALL RIGHT!  Added the On Error Resume Next
    updateForm code to the data sheet and BAM, beautiful!

Comment: Thanks a lot for posting the test file, that was worth its weight in gold and was the icing on the cake!

Comment: Glad it helped.  I might do something similar for a pinewood derby competition coming up next week. Cheers

Comment: [The Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vgOX.jpg) Here she is! Now I am trying to figure out how to change the font color of the group of labels under the "Bench" section if the values are negative...

Comment: Wow, you've made a lot of progress today.  I don't think you can change color of entire group in one line.  To change an individual label try: `myForm.Label7.ForeColor = vbRed`  Depending on how your "grouping" the labels you can loop through the  group and change the color.  I'd have to know more about what you mean by group.  FYI - Would be best to post new questions instead of morphing this one.

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49700768/setting-dynamic-excel-userform-label-color-based-on-value?noredirect=1#comment86415414_49700768) I did, I also wanted to share the fruits of your good help :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is an easier way to do it, but I made a concatenation routine to batch out my label setup and updates to quickly create/copy/paste all the code.

[image: Concatenator]

Just in case anyone didn't know how to do this